# alternative for module.exports

Tags: node.js, module

I've got a question that might sound strange.
We are using node.js, but the way we are writing javascript code is in a functional style. We have a lint tool that reports illegal use of the assignment expression. We can eleminate them all except for the 'module.exports = xxx' statement.

Is there an other way to load modules in node.js?

for example; the following statement would be fine as a solution as it is not an assignment expression but a variable declaration:
var exports = xxx;
if there is a way that nodejs would pick up this 'exports' variable, then we're done.

gr,

Coen

Comment: You should define `module` as a global variable for all files in that lint tool. Do the same for `process`.

Comment: Have seen it being used as exports = module.exports = Socket in socket.io libraries. Does that help?

Comment: both still require a assignment expression

Comment: Or maybe use jshint will pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following did the trick for me:

```
vm.runInThisContext
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like changing lint tool is the best way. :)

However you can use different module loader (there are some AMD implementations for node.js out there) that's pure functional.